# formatting Date to dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss before pushing entity field to the database - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, date

I have field of type Date in my model class as shown

```
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

and here are the getters and setters

```
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
```

when I launch the application, hiberbate updates the PostgreSQL database but I am unable to enter date in this format

```
dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

My challenge is to be able to enter date in the above format in the postgres db.
Any input is much appreciated

Comment: if you want to store date and time in specific format you need a text column, but it is preferred to store data as date and format it on output as needed

Comment: Do **not** send date/time values as "formatted" strings to the database. Use a `PreparedStatement` and pass an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp` (or `java.time.LocalDateTime`) to it. Do **not** store date/time values in `varchar` columns in the database. Use a `timestamp` column.